# Updating a session and using it within my view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

I have a wish list, that is throughout the shopping pages.  I need to know if this makes sense/the proper way of structuring.

Store the wish list as a session, when a user adds/deletes a new item it updates the session by an ajax call that just returns true/false if successful.  On the partial view of the wish list component, I check for the session and cast it to my viewModel (which the session is based on) or serialize it for my knockout.

Let me know if this makes sense, otherwise I can post some code samples

Comment: What's the point of a wish list that is just stored for the current session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say without having a look at your basic structure, and not knowing you exact needs.
I don't know if you know this, but you can actually access the Session directly in Views:

```
@{
var wishlist = (WishList)HttpContext.Current.Session["Wishlist"];
}
```

It's fine to use Ajax to update it server side; and then you can return a partial view from the controller, to use however you like in the Ajax success call.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: that makes perfect sense, and I will be using it. Thanks! (just seemed weird to use session state instead of populating a viewModel soley for each page)

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, if the wishlist is only supposed to exist for the duration of their visit then storing it in a session would be the best thing to do. However if the wishlist is supposed to live longer than a single visit and should be available to the user upon their return then I would suggest storing it in the database against the user's credentials/account (this is presuming they have an account).

As for the session itself, whilst you can access session data from a view I would not suggest it as you start to have a dependency on the session and before long you'll have code such as this scattered throughout your views.

```
var wishlist = (WishList)HttpContext.Current.Session["Wishlist"];
```

What happens when you want to change the way the wishlist works and instead have it database driven as you'd now like to persist the wishlist? You'll have to go through all of your views updating the references to the session.

Instead I would opt for registering your session with your IoC container of choice and injecting it using dependency injection, here is a simple example of how to register the session with StructureMap:

```
public class WebsiteRegistry : Registry
{
    public WebsiteRegistry()
    {
        this.For<IUserWishlist>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped().Use(() => GetUserWishlistFromSession());   
    }

    public static IUserWishlist GetUserWishlistFromSession()
    {
        var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        if (session["WishList"] != null)
        {
            return session["WishList"] as IUserWishlist;
        }

        /* Create new empty session object */
        session["WishList"] = new UserWishlist();

        return session["WishList"] as IUserWishlist;
    }
}
```

Now you're able to inject your wishlist into your controller and pass the data to your view via a view model. And as you're now programming against an interface instead of an implementation you could easily change how the wishlist is persisted without needing to change any code that references the wishlist.

```
public class WishlistController : Controller {

    private readonly IUserWishlist userWishlist;

    public void WishlistController(IUserWishlist userWishlist) {
        this.userWishlist= userWishlist;
    }

    public ActionResult ViewProfile()
    {
        ...
        var viewModel = new UserWishlistViewModel {
            wishlist = this.userWishlist.GetWishList()
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I've written a more detailed example up in a blog post that might be of interest which [can be read here](http://josephwoodward.co.uk/2014/06/sessions-asp-net-mvc-using-dependency-injection/). I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks! I only need it for the session, but if the requirement comes up to save the state (if the customer comes back for example) I will be using this structure. thanks again!